# Correlation Matrix Not Working on All Numerical Dataset

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data, dataset, correlation

I am trying to perform a correlation matrix on an all numerical dataset, imported from a .csv with headers specified as row 1:

```
bball3 = 
  Import[
   "/Users/Eileen/Documents/AA_Semester 2/Mathematica/Final \
Project/Seasons_Stats.csv", {"CSV", "Dataset"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1] ;
```

The data set has some categorical features so I have created a subsetted data set with just the numeric features:

```
numericDATA = bball3[All, 4 ;;];
```

But I am unable to call on the Correlation[] function to get a Correlation Matrix, when I do I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks

Comment: After removing ` {"CSV", "Dataset"},` it seems to work just fine for 13.0.1 (Windows 10).

Comment: I suspect you must have used `MatrixForm` on `bball3` prior to using `Correlation` because without doing so one gets the error `Correlation::arg1: The first argument must be either a vector, a matrix, or a multivariate distribution.`  But `MatrixForm` doesn't fix that error.

Answer (score 3):

[`Correlation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Correlation.html) is not tuned to take [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) but there are ways to calculate.

With

```
SeedRandom[123];
ds =
  Dataset[
   AssociationThread[Alphabet[][[;; 5]] -> #] & /@
    RandomReal[{100, 200}, {30, 5}]
   ];
```

Most basic is to get the [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) and then call `Correlation`

```
Correlation@Normal[Values@ds] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

However, if you want to retain `Dataset` and the keys then

```
ds[
 {Keys@*First, Values/*Correlation}/*
  Apply[
   AssociationThread[#1 -> Map[r |-> AssociationThread[#1, r]]@#2] &
   ]
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.